# Mysql to mysqli or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a project here that has a LOT of this kind of code below.

It is everything in mysql and I want to change do mysqli or PDO.

The problem is that the code make the fields of the table be variables, inside the loop. So, If I need to change to something different, I will have to re-write thousand of lines of code. Because inside the loops below I will change every call of the var. Example: `$row["product_name"]` instead of `$product_name`

This is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT product_name, product_price from products";

$result = mysql_query($query_sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $j = mysql_num_fields($query);
       for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++) {
            $k = mysql_field_name($query,$i);
            $$k = $row[$k];
        }

 //Here, inside the loop, I use $product_name instead of $row["product_name"]


}
```

It there a way to change the code to do the same with mysqli or PDO? I want to keep using `$field_name` instead of `$row["field_name"]`.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php

Comment: Don't fall into the `mysqli` trap. Newcomers often mistake the name similarity for an easier migration path. In practice it's actually more effort due to the shifted connection arg. PDO is pretty much what everyone else agreed to use henceforth, as its parameter binding is heaps simpler.

Comment: Dynamically creating new variables at runtime as you do has nothing todo with MySQL/MySQLi/PDO, hence it will also work with MySQLi and PDO. Migration to MySQLi will probably be easier for you but I recommend you to check out both, PDO and MySQLi.

Comment: I don't know that `mysqli` is a trap. It doesn't translate as well if you want to keep everything procedural (especially since you MUST pass the connection EVERY TIME). If you make the leap to objects it's roughly about the same. But, yes, PDO has never changed syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli` object method shown. I don't recommend doing it this way, but it can be done. I would **highly** suggest you learn how to deal with either a result object or array directly. Dynamically setting variables like this will introduce a lot of unnecessary overhead.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query_sql);

while($row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($row);

    //Here, inside the loop, I use $product_name instead of $row["product_name"]
}
```

Comment: Your loop reimplements [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract). And importantly either should preferrably only be used with a known/limited set of column names in the result (not with e.g. `SELECT *`) to eschew local scope overload.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for: http://www.doctrine-project.org/

I specifically do not like this specific project, because it tends to be slow with larger amounts of data, but provides what you need:

You specify domain classes (understand map database lines to php objects) and you only have to specify the exact name of the table column, if it does not match up with the class variable name.

So you set every column once for every object type and you use that definition throughout you code, you are making a request for the object, that has a mapping to the database.

so it goes like: $entitiy_manager->getReference('myobject', $objectid = 1 );
Creating a new object is just adding a new instance of the class.

If I understood you properly this should be you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for every answer and opinion, but I just found the solution for my question.

I will leave here, for future reference.

This code is in mysql:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $j = mysql_num_fields($query);
    for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++) {
        $k = mysql_field_name($query,$i);
        $$k = $row[$k];
    }
}
```

And this would be the same in mysqli:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $j = mysqli_num_fields($query);
    for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++) {
        $k =  mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name;
        $$k = $row[$k];
     }
```

}